# JQuery statement if/else not working on click function, runs if and else part

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, logic

First I verify if the text of the element is "ocultar menu", if it's true, I change the text and add hide Class to some others elements. My intention is that the function breaks there, and see the value of text only in the start of the event, and no when I change it inside the function. But when I click once, it appears hide, very fast in the console of the browser, it's like the functions checks the value and continue to check and pass in the if and in the else part of the code. I used StopPropagation() but doesn't works and I've tried to change the on event to click and not worked too. Need Help, thanks.

```
   var $position = $("#ocult-menu").position();
    $("#ocult-menu").on("click",function(){ 
        var $text = $(this).find('p').text();
        if ($text == "ocultar menu"){
            $(".info").addClass("hide");
            $(".photo").addClass("hide");
            $(".map").addClass("hide");
            $(".similar").addClass("hide");
            $(".share").addClass("hide");
            $("#menu-single").offset({left: $position.left});
            $(".exibir").css("background-position","-1px 430px");
            $(this).find('p').text("exibir menu");
        }
        else if( $text == "exibir menu"){
            $(".info").removeClass("hide");
            $(".photo").removeClass("hide");
            $(".map").removeClass("hide");
            $(".similar").removeClass("hide");
            $(".share").removeClass("hide");
            $("#menu-single").offset({left: $position.left});
            $(this).find('p').text("ocultar menu");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your console output?

Comment: Your HTML markup is not clear, but be aware that `$(this).find('p').text()` finds all the text of all `<p>`s

Comment: What type of element is `#ocult-menu`? Is it an `a` that is reloading the page? It would help if you created a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I saw in the site that the click event is been called twice, if I go to the console and type $("#ocult-menu").click() it works well

Answer (score 1):

You might be adding the onclick handler more than once, causing it to execute multiple times per click. Try adding some log statements, like so:

```
$("#ocult-menu").on("click",function(){ 
    console.log("onclick");
    ...
    if ($text == "ocultar menu"){
        console.log("text = ocultar menu");
        ...
    }
    else if( $text == "exibir menu"){
        console.log("text = exibir menu");
        ...
    }
});
```

If you see "onclick" being logged more than once, that's the problem.  Then you can move this handler setup code to your initial one-time page load function.

```
$(function() {
    $("#ocult-menu").on("click",function(){
        ...
    });
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I made this, but didn't worked, Its disparing twice... And now I saw that in some other parts in the site this is happening too, when I make a ajax call, it calls twice, what should I do? Its a event in On click... a function that I call inside is been called twice

Comment: What do you see in the log after adding the console.log statements I suggested?